# How to spec a inrush current resistor?

Tags: relay, dc-dc-converter, inrush-current

I want to know how do I spec a limiting resistor for the below circuit:

[image]

The relay used is [this](https://docs.rs-online.com/6277/0900766b814f02dd.pdf). The power supply input is 48V and the output is 12V DC. First switch SW1 is pressed which powers the DC/DC and then powers the U3. U3 then activates the 12V relay which switches the contact. SW1 is then released and Relay1 then supplies continuous power to the DC/DC.

My question is do I need R1?
If I do how do I calculate the value of R1 and how do I calculate the precharge time?

Comment: I^2xR fusing energy (or lack thereof) and peak dissipation comes to mind. Do you have any peak current figure you need to stay below? How much can the switch handle?

Comment: R1 helps longevity. Peak current = 48V/10 ohm = 4.8A, decays exponantilly. Charge time is 200uF x 10 ==> about 2000uS +/-, though it does not have much meaning.

Comment: @jay how to I determine a good precharge time? Is 20000uS to fast? DO I need to change teh resistance to make the time longer?

Comment: @jay why is it 200uF? Those caps are not in parallel

Comment: You are not powering up/down every mS, so not stressing too much of R & C. Does 10 ohm drop too much voltage? Can you use larger resistor? Calculate R1 = (48V - min_DC_DC_input_V) /  Current_needed, plus some margin, and that is all you can afford.

Comment: Why 200uF? Doesn't matter, but you have to charge all the caps, unless there are more to supply current.

Comment: @jay the min DC-DC is 45V and the current needed is 2A max at the input. SO R1 is 1.5ohm (6W), so I will need a 2 ohm 10W resistor

Comment: The other way around, 1 ohm, since 2ohm will drop 4V, render 40V to the DC-DC.

Comment: @Jay sorry I saw the wrong input values, so the input for the DC/DC ranges from 22V to 70V DC. So R1 is 13 ohms, round down to 10 ohms since it is more common, hence  I will need a 10 ohm 40W resistor, but using the previous calculation above with 45V as the min means I only need a 1 ohm 2W resistor which is cheper. So does mean the more voltage drop the resistor has the better the precharge circuit? I am just confused by this part.

Comment: R throttles current to the C, less inrush means less stress. 1 ohm 5W? I may just go without R, with good SW.

Comment: @jay I will go with the resistor but use a 1 kilo-ohm 5W resistor, so it will take around a second to charge, As long as it charges up before 2 seconds is fine. I cannot seem to find a "good " switch so will just use the resistor.

Comment: @jay R = (T/(C*5)) from the following site: http://liionbms.com/php/precharge.php

Comment: @jay s = second. S = Siemens.

Comment: Use a simulator.

Comment: @winny, Thanks! I never get it right, too late to fix (?). Chemist here complains that always, and about the tick with " 'C ". :-)